# usc multivalued operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, multivalued-functions

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and $T\colon X \rightarrow 2^{X^{\star}}$ be an operator.

1) What does that meas that operator $T$ is upper semicontinuous?

2) What does that mean that operator $T$ is upper semicontinuous from each finite dimensional subspace of $X$ into $X^{\star}$?